# Where are the multi-instantons in Supersymmetric QM?

Tags: path-integral, supersymmetry, grassmann-numbers, instantons

Instantons can be used to find non perturbative corrections to ground state energies. However, the *way* in which they are used seems to me to be very different between the two common toy models of the double well potential and the super symmetric double well potential. Skip to the end for the question.

### Double Well Instanton Review

The first of these models is QM in the double well potential. In Sidney Coleman's classic "Uses of Instantons," he explain how to calculate the energy splitting of the ground state and first excited state using instantons. Assume the two minima of the potential are at $q = \pm a$. Then for large $\beta$, the following euclidean transition amplitude will only have contributions from the lowest lying energy states.

\begin{equation}
    \langle a | e^{- \beta H} |a\rangle \approx |\langle a|E_0\rangle|^2 e^{-\beta E_0} + |\langle a |E_1\rangle|^2 e^{-\beta E_1} + \ldots
\end{equation}
This amplitude can also be computed with the path integral.
\begin{equation}
    \langle a| e^{- \beta H} |a \rangle = \int_{q(-\beta/2) = a}^{q(\beta/2) = a} \mathcal{D} q(\tau) e^{-S_E[q(\tau)]}.
\end{equation}
The Euclidean action $S_E$ is essentially the normal action with a flipped potential $V(q) \mapsto -V(q)$. One can then show that there are classical solutions which extremize the euclidean action (called 'instantons') which travel from $q = a$ to $q = - a$ in infinite time. By expanding around such a path to quadratic order (the semiclassical approximation), the path integral is
$$
\approx K e^{- S_E}
$$
where $K$ is some ratio of functional determinants and $S_E$ is the action of this solution.

However, one can also consider paths which approximately extremize the action which go back and forth between $+a$ and $-a$ many times. As $\beta \to \infty$, the penalty to the action from these paths is very small and essentially doesn't matter.

If such a path is to both start and end at $a$, then all we have to do is specify the $2n$ time coordinates of these transitions, where $2n$ is an even number. We then get
\begin{align}
        \langle a| e^{- \beta H} |a\rangle &\approx \left( \frac{m \omega}{\pi} \right)^{1/2} e^{- \beta \omega/2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\beta^{2n}}{(2 n)!} \left( e^{- S_0} K \right)^{2n} \\
        &= \left( \frac{m \omega}{\pi} \right)^{1/2} e^{- \beta \omega / 2} \cosh( e^{-S_0} K \beta) \\
        &= (\mathrm{const} ) ( e^{- \beta (\omega - K e^{S_0})} + e^{- \beta (\omega + K e^{S_0})} )
\end{align}
from which we can read off the energy splitting of the two lowest energy states
\begin{equation}
    \Delta E = 2 K e^{-S_0} .
\end{equation}.

### Supersymmetric QM

In supersymmetric QM, one obtains a potential and a "magnetic field" from a single function, the "Superpotential'' $w(q)$. See for instance the 1996 notes by Phil Argyres [here](https://homepages.uc.edu/%7Eargyrepc/cu661-gr-SUSY/index.html). The two potentials, which each apply to the two components of the wave function, are
$$
V_{\pm} = \frac{1}{2}(W')^2 \pm \frac{1}{2} W''.
$$
Let's consider a super potential of the form
$$
W(q) = \mu q^3 + \lambda q^2.
$$
This gives rise to a double well potential $(W')^2$. The ground state will not have $0$ energy and we say supersymmetry is broken.

To calculate the ground state energy, one can use the fact that there are supercharges $Q$ which essentially square to the Hamiltonian $H$. I will not go over the steps here (see section 4.2 in Argyres' notes for more) but one essentially computes
$$
\langle 0 + | Q | 0 - \rangle \propto e^{-S_E}
$$
using a *single instanton,* which goes from the bottom of one well to the other well,and squares it to get the ground state energy.

### My Question

Here is my question. When it comes to computing the shift in ground state energy, both the double well and the super symmetric double well use instantons. However, they use them in pretty different ways. In the non-SUSY case, you must use multi instantons, which go back and forth an arbitrary number of times, which becomes a $\cosh$ using the formula for the Taylor expansion, and there is a splitting of energy levels which is roughly $e^{-S_E}$. However, in the SUSY case, you just calculate $Q$ directly with a single instanton, and basically get $e^{-S_E}$ as well.

I am wondering why you can't just use multi instantons for the SUSY case as well? I am interested in seeing how the *same* calculation, where one computes the transition function in the large $\beta$ limit and reads off the lowest lying terms, would go.

One reason I am interested in this is that there isn't really "splitting" in the SUSY case like there is in the non-SUSY case. In the non-SUSY case, the ground state energy shifts by $\pm \Delta E$, so the true ground state has slightly less energy than the perturbative ground state. In the SUSY case, however, the perturbative ground state has $0$ energy and the true ground state has slightly higher energy. Because weaving back and forth always gives you a $\cosh(\beta \Delta E)$, which gives you a $\pm \Delta E$ to the ground state energy, this would seem to imply that somehow for the SUSY case, you don't have a $\cosh(\beta \Delta E)$ but rather just get a $e^{\beta \Delta E}$. I am curious why a would-be $\cosh$ just becomes an exponential in the analogous SUSY calculation.